# Ошибка при компиляции C#

Tags: c#, компиляция

учусь C#, есть задание (собрать информацию о комплектующих и системе компьютера и вывести его в консоль) и пример кода к нему, пытаюсь разобрать пример кода, но он даже не компилируется у меня. Спустя целый день перелопачивания интернета и знакомых, понял, что не могу справиться, за сим обращаюсь за помощью сюда. Прилагаю код, использующиеся библиотеки и ссылки, а так же скрин ошибок.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Создаем контейнер для OMF
            ManagementClass myManagementClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_Processor");
            ManagementObjectCollection myManagementCollection = myManagementClass.GetInstances();
            PropertyDataCollection myProperties = myManagementClass.Properties;
            //перечисляем поля OMF-структуры
            foreach (var obj in myManagementCollection)
            {
                foreach (var myProperty in myProperties)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{myProperty.Name}:{ obj.Properties[myProperty.Name].Value}");

                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Список ссылок]
[image: Список ошибок]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте сборку (assembly) `System.Management.dll` в "Ссылки" (References) Вашего проекта и

```
using System.Management;
```

в начало файла `Program.cs`.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementclass?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Добавил System.Management в ссылках, не помогло

Comment: ВОУ, я понимаю что вопрос совсем глупый был, тем более после вашего ответа, но большое спасибо, я думал ссылка автоматически добавляется везде